# SVM model fails to load in Android Application

Tags: android, opencv, svm

I have a problem with `load()` method in SVM module. For example if I run code:

```
try {
    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File("file:///android_asset/SVM_Bills.xml"));
    mySvm.load(uri.getPath());          
    int in = mySvm.get_support_vector_count();
    if (in != 0) {
        Toast.makeText(context,"done loading : " + uri.getPath(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        value = (int)mySvm.predict(matOfDescriptor);
    }
    else {
        Toast.makeText(context,"error while loading : " + uri.getPath(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

It give me the error toast message (i.e it goes to else part and show the toast message).
Of course SVM was previously trained.

Any help please?

Comment: If you got any error message, it's the most important piece of information, so you should definitely add it to your question.

Comment: I mean this error toast message :                                                                               Toast.makeText(context,"error while loading").show();                                 SO it goes to else part and show the toast message

Comment: I see, I understand now. Thanks.